# How to divide with awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to read file and divide all elements by 0.03.Precision is IMPORTANT.Then to save result in output file.

```
 #!/bin/bash

var=$(cat 262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat)
mapfile var < infile

awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i*100/3}1' infile > output
```

But I got

```
a4.sh: line 4: infile: No such file or directory
```

Sample input

```
-9.341203692800e+02
-9.320539972800e+02
-9.302205617600e+02
```

Sample output

```
-31137.345
-31068.466
-31007.352
```

Comment: What is `mapfile < ` supposed to be doing? Also include your sample input/output.

Comment: @anubhava Read data from my file with mapfile.

Comment: `mapfile` is shell builtin in bash 4+ that reads lines from the standard input into an indexed array variable.

Comment: @anubhava Please take a look at my edit!

Comment: Wild guess: there's `No such file or directory` as `infile`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .03 }' file
-31137.346
-31068.467
-31007.352
```

- `$0+0 == $0` will make sure to execute this division for lines with valid numbers only.
- `printf "%.3f"` will print result with 3 precision points.

Comment: For output file shoud I just add > output?

Comment: Yes, `awk '$0+0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .03 }' file > output`

Comment: Why the `$0+0`? Should it not produce any output if the input is `0.000`?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I meant `$0+0 == $0` to make sure it is executed for numbers only.

Comment: OK. I don't see anything in the question to suggest there are any non-numbers in the input though so it's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

create test data

```
$ for i in {1..20}; do echo $RANDOM; done | pr -5ts' ' > file
```

divide by 0.03 is the same as multiplying by 100 and dividing by 3.

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i*100/3}1' file

814633 811567 251933 1075000 1.08787e+06
424000 799200 687733 657300 314367
239467 162433 343867 337533 61533.3
1.00403e+06 1.02077e+06 1034100 1036500 155133
```

Comment: I do not understand,is my first line ok?